# Update value of second bootstrap select on select of first bootstrap select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am new to bootstrap-selectpicker. I have two select fields. I want to know how to update the value of the second selectpicker based on the selection of the first one.

```
<select  id="id1" name="name1" class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true">
  <option value="A">AAA</option>
  <option value="B">BBB</option>
</select>
<select  id="id2" name="name2" class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true">
  <option value="A">AAA</option>
  <option value="B">BBB</option>
  <option value="C">CCC</option>
  <option value="D">DDD</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});
```

The JS code above initializes both selectpickers. Am I missing something? Or is this is the wrong way to initialize? Can someone provide an example of using multiple bootstrap-selectpickers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
  if($(this).attr('name')=="name2"){
      $(".selectpicker[name='name1']").val(/*set value*/);
  }
  else{
      $(".selectpicker[name='name2']").val(/*set value*/);
  }
});
```

`changed.bs.select` is an event of the library, you can have a look [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events)

Answer (score 1):

try this one i hope this will work 
if your first select value is 1 then in second select would be select only same value as first select

```
$("#select1").change(function(){  

if ($(this).data('options') == undefined){
$(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());  

}  var id = $(this).val();  

var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');

 $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize them seprately if you wish by ID but it's not neccesarily needed:

```
$('#id1').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});
$('#id2').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});
```

To update the second value of selectpicker according to the first select is easy.
When you change value of the first selectpicker you should just get the value of the first one with

```
var result = $('select[name=name1]').val();
```

And then set it to another

```
$('select[name=name2]').val(result);
$('#id2').selectpicker('refresh');
```